# How can i Modify this program so that the child process creates another child?

Tags: c++, process, operating-system, fork, wait

Modify the following program so that the child process creates another child and wait for it. The grand child prints out the id's of itself, its parent and grandparent.

This is what ive tried so far...

```
//testWait.cpp
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
pid_t pid;      //process id
string message;
int n;
int exit_code;

cout << "fork program starting\n";
pid = fork();
switch ( pid ) 
{
case -1:
  cout << "Fork failure!\n";
  return 1;
case 0:
  message = "This is the child\n";
  n = 5;
  exit_code = 9;
  break;
default:
  message = "This is the parent\n";
  n = 3;
  exit_code = 0;
  break;
}

for ( int i = 0; i < n; ++i ) 
{
    cout << message;
    sleep ( 2 );
}

//waiting for child to finish
if ( pid > 0 )   //parent 
{       
    int stat_val;
    pid_t child_pid;

    child_pid = wait ( &stat_val ); //wait for child 
    cout << "Child finished: PID = " << child_pid << endl;
    if ( WIFEXITED ( stat_val ) )   //rerturn true if child terminated  normally that is by exit(3)
        cout << "child exited with code " << WEXITSTATUS ( stat_val ) << endl;  //returns the exit status of the child.
    else
        cout << "child terminated abnormally!" << endl;
}
/*
if(pid == 0)       //child
{
    int stat_val;
    pid_t gc_pid, pid2; 
    pid2 = fork();
    //gc_pid = fork();
    gc_pid = wait ( &stat_val );    //wait for grandchild
    if(pid2 == 0)
    {
        cout << "This is the GrandChild\n";
        exit_code = 9;
        cout << "GrandChild finished: PID = " << gc_pid << endl;
        //cout << "My parent is PID = " << pid;
    }
    //cout << "GrandChild finished: PID = " << gc_pid << endl;  
}
*/


exit ( exit_code );
```

}

The part of code where i commented out is what ive attempted.

Comment: Why are you spamming TAGS? This is `C++` code.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if(pid == 0)       //child
        {
        int stat_val;
        pid_t gc_pid, pid2; 
        pid2 = fork();
        //gc_pid = fork();
        gc_pid = wait ( &stat_val );    //wait for grandchild
        if(pid2 == 0)
            {
             cout << "This is the GrandChild\n";
             exit_code = 9;
             cout << "GrandChild finished: PID = " << getpid() << endl;
             cout << "My parent is PID = " << getppid()<< endl;
            }
        cout << "GrandChild finished: PID = " << getpid() << endl;  
        }
```

Comment: so for the if statement that i have commented out 'if(pid == 0)' then create a fork in there correct?

Comment: :) i didn't see the part of code below the switch ; 
The creation process worked, but i'd advice you to use the `getpid()` and `getppid()` to get the pid of both the running process executing the function, and its parent pid. I'll edit my answer accordingly.